# Expand define macro with include macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, include

I'm trying to define a macro. The idea is that when it expands, it'll include a header. For example:

```
#define function() \
                   include <CustomHeader.h>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this? Why does it need to be a macro?

Comment: You can't do exactly that, since a macro can't produce a preprocessing directive. If you describe the problem you're trying to solve, perhaps there might be a different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done.

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, [...]

That particular quote is from a reasonably recent draft of the C++ standard, but with minor changes in wording, the same basic idea has been around nearly forever.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, you cannot produce a directive from a macro.

You can however produce the *argument to* a directive from a macro:

```
#define INCF(F) INCF_(F)
#define INCF_(F) #F
#define BAR foo.h

#include INCF(BAR)  // same as #include "foo.h"
```

But you can't get rid of that explicit `#include`, or insert it into the middle of a different line, or anything like that.