# Macro substitution in #include directive

Tags: include, c-preprocessor, stringification

I would like to use an `#include` directive with a file name that is passed as an externally defined macro.

E.g.

```
#include #FILE".h"
```

where `FILE` would be defined as the string `MyFile` (without quotes), resulting in

```
#include "MyFile.h"
```

The stringizing operator # cannot be used here as the symbol `FILE` is not a macro argument. I have tried other approaches, to no avail.

Do you see a solution ?

Comment: gcc provides some functionality to *externally* include files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387453/include-header-files-using-command-line-option. This may helps you.

Comment: Interesting. I am using both gcc and MSVC, and my #include directive may not be in the first position.

Comment: It won't be possible, since adjacent string literal concatenation is not done until after the preprocessor stage, so e.g. `"MyFile"".h"` will not be a valid include name. Can't you simply define `FILE` as the actual header name to be included, e.g. `-DFILE="MyFile.h"`?

Comment: See this one (solution 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465646/expand-define-macro-with-include-macro

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I'll do it as a last resort.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

String literal concatenation happens two translation phases after `#include`-directives are resolved; your approach cannot work. Instead, try something along the lines of

```
#define STRINGIZE_(a) #a
#define STRINGIZE(a) STRINGIZE_(a)

#define MYFILE stdio
#include STRINGIZE(MYFILE.h)

int main() {
    printf("asdf");
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04b16737bb291137).

Comment: Why is `STRINGIZE_` needed?

Comment: @palapapa to resolve macros in the argument (not needed in this example)